# Android development on MacBook

Tags: android

I have a **MacBook** and want to start my **Android development** on it. But I am afraid about its possibility. Is Android development possible on **Mac OS**?
As of now I know that it is possible to run different operating system on different one via virtual tools like **VMWare**. Can it do the same?

Comment: If you look at Goggle IO videos they are also using mac book for android development

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's posible to develop directly on the Mac OS. You have a [SDK version](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for that and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx) works too. See [here](http://www.freshblocks.com/tutorials/getting-set-up-for-android-development-on-a-mac/) for a complete set up example.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible.

Please check below link

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

Android development primarily takes place with Java and in Eclipse (which itself runs on Java) and therefore is cross platform.

1. [Download the SDK for Mac](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Following the [installation instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

If you still get any problem then just go to [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers) and you will get the right answer..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very much possible. Please refer to the link below:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html 
download the android studio version for mac and get started.  Happy Coding.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: The link redirects to the developers page where the Android studio version for mac can be downloaded from.